# Blazor server side two way binding not working as expected

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, blazor, .net-5, blazor-server-side

I am working on a server side Blazor project. My goal is for the search button to be enabled when the account number is entered. This does not seem to be working with my current set up.

I have two components, a parent and child component. The parent component is my search page and the child is just the text box for the account number.

This is how I am adding the child component within the parent component:

```
<AccountSearchComponent @bind-AccountNumber="Account" ></AccountSearchComponent>
```

In the code I have the account number set as a parameter:

```
[Parameter]
public string Account { get; set; }
```

The search button is disabled/enabled based on my "CanSearch" function, the entirety of which is this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Account))
                return true;
```

If it matters, here is the code for the search button itself:

```
<button type="button" disabled="@(!CanSearch)" @onclick="Search">Search</button>
```

Moving on to the child component, I have two parameters. My understanding is that AccountNumberChanged should be notifying the parent component that the change happened:

```
[Parameter]
public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> AccountNumberChanged { get; set; }
```

And for good measure here is the HTML from the child component:

```
<input value="@AccountNumber" type="text" placeholder="ACCOUNT" />
```

When I enter an account number into this text box nothing happens. The search button remains disabled when I expect it become enabled.

There is more code of course but none of it has to do with the account number and enabling the search button. Any guidance on what to check? I am a Blazor newbie.

Comment: IIRC, I believe you need to actually call the event with a value: `AccountNumberChanged.InvokeAsync(value0);`  The matching names are enough to wire things on the other side with `<Component @bind-AccountNumber="mynumberstring" />` but just changing the value won't trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

You are using at the moment only one way binding in input, You need to use two way binding to know if text is changed in textbox, like this

```
<input @bind-value="@AccountNumber" type="text" placeholder="ACCOUNT" />
```